# TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

Tags: java, hibernate

Конфигурация :

```
  public class HibernateConfig {
private static final SessionFactory concreteSessionFactory;
private static HibernateConfig instance;

private HibernateConfig(){

}

public static HibernateConfig getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new HibernateConfig();
    }
    return instance;
}

static {
    try {
        Properties prop= new Properties();
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
        prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
        concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
                .addPackage("Main.*")
                .addProperties(prop)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Example.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}


public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
    return concreteSessionFactory;
}


}
```

DBService

```
 public class DBService {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public DBService() {
    sessionFactory= HibernateConfig.getInstance().sessionFactory();
}

.......
public void updateJournalNote(JournalDataSet journalDataSet) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    MySqlDAO dao = new MySqlDAO(session);
    dao.updateJournalNote(journalDataSet);
}
.......

}
```

MySqlDAO

```
 public class MySqlDAO {

private Session session;

public MySqlDAO(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
}


 public void updateJournalNote(JournalDataSet journalDataSet) {
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(journalDataSet);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

}
}
```

Некоторое время после начала работает нормально, потом получаю TransactionException: nested transactions not supported в session.beginTransaction();, updateJournalNote часто вызывается, но метод что вызывает его synchronized.
Перед этим возникает:

```
   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute 
   statement 
 Caused by: 
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
 Duplicate entry '2017.07.10 17:15:48-6-3000' for key 'UK_journal'
```

в session.beginTransaction();

Comment: А что это `Duplicate entry '2017.07.10 17:15:48-6-3000' for key 'UK_journal'` такое? Устраните эту ошибку, чтоб небыло дубликатов. Я так понял при этой ошибке транзация не заканчивается (не вызывается commit()), и потом начинается еще одна транзакция при незавершенной предыдущей, а так быть не должно.

Answer (score 0):

Я не буду говорить про вторую ошибку, но расскажу про ситуацию связанную с первой.

При работе с hibernate нужно всегда учитывать такой нюанс, что **транзакцию нужно закрывать даже если произошла ошибка**. Во время выполнения, вы открываете транзакцию, в запросе произошла ошибка, программа ее отобразила и прошла дальше, выйдя из этого блока `try/catch` и вот вы снова обращаетесь к базе, снова вызываете `session.beginTransaction();`, а ничего не выходит. Транзакция уже открыта и hibernate пробрасывает исключение.

Другими словами, оберните типовой запрос в `try/catch` и откатите там транзакцию `rollback()`.

PS Чот я забыл, а сделал ли я это в последнем сервисе...? :пошел проверять: